# J'ai inventé un prétexte : la nuit était / avait été si belle que j'ai / avais préféré

Tags: passé-composé, concordance-des-temps, plus-que-parfait

> J'**ai inventé** un prétexte : la nuit **était** si belle que j'**ai
> préféré** rester dehors.

Est-ce qu'en raison du passé composé dans la première partie *j'ai inventé*, je devrais écrire la deuxième partie de la façon suivante : *la nuit **avait été** si belle que **j'avais préféré** rester dehors* ? Autrement dit, est-ce que le passé composé dans la première partie de la phrase a une influence sur la deuxième ?

Answer (score 4):

Les deux phrases n’ont pas la même signification.

Dans la première phrase, on comprend qu’il est resté dehors pendant la belle nuit. L’utilisation de l’imparfait, temps simple, fait référence à quelque chose d’inaccompli.

Dans la deuxième phrase, on comprend qu’il est resté dehors même une fois la belle nuit terminée. Le plus-que-parfait, temps composé, fait référence à quelque chose d’accompli.

Comment: Un conseil: quand tu changes d'avis, plutôt que d'effacer ta réponse puis en recréer une nouvelle, il est plus simple d'éditer l'existante.

Comment: Merci. _Dans la deuxième phrase, on comprend qu’il est resté dehors même une fois la belle nuit terminée_ Je ne comprends pas. J'utilise le plus-que-parfait aussi avec _j'avais préféré_, donc les deux parties, "la nuit est belle" et "je préfère" ont les même temps, donc les deux réflètent les actions accomplies, non ? // _fait référence à quelque chose d’inaccompli_ Si j'écris _la nuit était_, l'imparfait, cela voudrait dire que ce n'est plus le cas, non ?